# How can I get a fresh array every time I visit a component?

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic2

I have an app in Ionic 2 and its very simple just two pages (Game and Results). To show the questions to be answered there is an array 'myQuestions' that is instantiated with data from another *constant* array of questions. Every time a question is answered I delete a question from 'myQuestions' and finally the second page shows the results. In the results page there is a 'play again' button and here comes the problem because when I go to the Game page, the array is incomplete. It is not reinstantiated, the componenent its not created again but instead it is reused, until I got 0 questions available and the site crashes. How can I solve this?

Comment: `var array = []`?

Comment: what? I mean I have an array, the problem is that when I go back to the Game page the array is not a new one, so eventually it runs out of questions, crashing the website.

Comment: what do you mean when you say the array is incomplete? Do you pop the page or setRoot to go back to the game page?

Comment: I setRoot to go back

Comment: You should put the code that generates myQuestions array in ionViewDidLoad(). Every time you visit the page, it will run the code.

Comment: It works, thank you very much Hien! Why isn't the app creating a fresh array from the constructor every time I visit it?

Comment: @Tom - that's not obvious from your words - code speaks volumes

Comment: @Tom: constructor loads once when the application run because it is single page app. The application does not refresh when you change the view, they use ajax request to load other view instead. IonViewDidLoad() fits in the purpose of listening the loading view and runs any time you visit the page. Get me an point if you think my answer is helpful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. Please create an answer so I can select yours as the chosen one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use setRoot to navigate back to the Game page, you can put the code that generates myQuestions array in ionViewDidLoad(). The page constructor loads once when the application runs because it is single page app. The application does not refresh when you change the view, they use Ajax request to load other view instead. IonViewDidLoad() fits in the purpose of listening the loading view and runs any time you visit the page.